# java.lang.VerifyError after extending class

Tags: java, eclipse, jfreechart

I'm extending the JFreeChart ChartComposite class. 
When I try to create the instance of extended class I'm getting `java.lang.VerifyError : .... incompatible object argument for function call` error.

Answer (score 3):

Practically speacking:

> It mostly happens when you are
>   compliing with one version of the
>   library, but running with another
>   version of the library.

More precisely, VerifyError is a type of LinkageError. From the javadoc of LinkageError: 
*"Subclasses of LinkageError indicate that a class has some dependency on another class; however, the latter class has incompatibly changed after the compilation of the former class."*

Comment: I'm using two plugin in my project. The error occured after adding JFreeChart libraries to each plugin build path. I removed the libraries from one plugin and I implemented the extended class in other plugin. So when I use JFreeChart libraries in only one plugin I have no error.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are possibly running against a **different version** of the `JFreeChart` JAR than you compiled your code against - does the stack trace contain any information about what the problematic method is?

Another possibility would be that JFreeChart expects a particular version of some 3rd-party library on the classpath whereas you are running with a different version.